# JavaScript/jQuery on load event

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

Currently, I have a script that opens up a Google Map when you click the "View Map" link. This is all done in jQuery.

I am trying to rework it so that the map opens immediately on the page load. This doesn't have to be seamless, or pixel-perfect, but have the map pop up without needed to click the "View Map" link is what we are going for.

Below is the relevant code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */
    jQuery.noConflict();
    (function($) {

        $(function() {

            // Map global vars
            var map;
            var marker;
            var center;

            // initialize Google Maps API
            function initMap() {

                // Define Map center
                center = new google.maps.LatLng('<?php echo $lat; ?>','<?php echo $long; ?>');

                // Define Map options
                var myOptions = {
                  'zoom': 10,
                  'center': center,
                  'mapTypeId': google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                };

                // Load Map
                map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('job_map'), myOptions);

                // Marker
                marker = new google.maps.Marker({ position: center, map: map, title: "<?php echo $title; ?>" });

            }

            // Slide Toggle
            $('a.toggle_map').click(function(){
                $('#share_form').slideUp();
                $('#apply_form').slideUp();
                if (!map) initMap();
                $('#job_map').slideToggle(function(){
                    google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
                    map.setCenter(center);
                });
                $('a.apply_online').removeClass('active');
                $(this).toggleClass('active');
                return false;
            });

        });
    })(jQuery);
/* ]]> */

function actuateLink(link)
    {
       var allowDefaultAction = true;
          
       if (link.click)
       {
          link.click();
          return;
       }
       else if (document.createEvent)
       {
          var e = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
          e.initEvent(
             'click'     // event type
             ,true      // can bubble?
             ,true      // cancelable?
          );
          allowDefaultAction = link.dispatchEvent(e);           
       }
             
       if (allowDefaultAction)       
       {
          var f = document.createElement('form');
          f.action = link.href;
          document.body.appendChild(f);
          f.submit();
       }
}
actuateLink(document.querySelectorAll('.toggle_map'));
</script>
```

You can see an example of what I am talking about here: http://www.psychiatryjobs.io/jobs/seattle-attending-psychiatrist/

As you can see in my code, I tried to call the `.click` event and simulate that with my code, but after a few hours of work was still unsuccessful.

Comment: Are you waiting until the DOM is ready?  It looks like `actuateLink` is running immediately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying to programmatically click the link to open the map is the long way around when all you need to do is run the `initMap` function. Can you add a call to `initMap` before or after the click listener is registered?

```
jQuery.noConflict();
(function($) {

    $(function() {

        // Map global vars
        var map;
        var marker;
        var center;

        // initialize Google Maps API
        function initMap() {

            // Define Map center
            center = new google.maps.LatLng('<?php echo $lat; ?>','<?php echo $long; ?>');

            // Define Map options
            var myOptions = {
              'zoom': 10,
              'center': center,
              'mapTypeId': google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };

            // Load Map
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('job_map'), myOptions);

            // Marker
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({ position: center, map: map, title: "<?php echo $title; ?>" });

        }

        // Slide Toggle
        $('a.toggle_map').click(function(){
            $('#share_form').slideUp();
            $('#apply_form').slideUp();
            if (!map) initMap();
            $('#job_map').slideToggle(function(){
                google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
                map.setCenter(center);
            });
            $('a.apply_online').removeClass('active');
            $(this).toggleClass('active');
            return false;
        });

        //
        //show the map at start by default
        //
        if (!map) initMap();

    });
})(jQuery);
```